# how to get sum of records according to date

Tags: mysql

i have a sql Query

```
SELECT t2.net 
     , t1.date 
  FROM database1.invoices t1 
  join invoicesdetail t2 
    on t1.id = t2.InvID 
 where shopid = 11
   and t1.date between '2016-01-30' AND '2016-01-31'  
   AND t2.StockType = 1
```

`
by using above query i got records like

```
net date
120 2016-01-30
115 2016-01-20
 35 2016-01-31
170 2016-01-31
```

i just want to calculate this records datewise like 2016-01-30 total 235 and 2016-01-31 total is 205 and overall total is 440 please help me to create this query

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(t2.net), t1.date 
FROM database1.invoices t1 
JOIN invoicesdetail t2 ON t1.id = t2.InvID 
WHERE shopid='11' 
AND t1.date between '2016-01-30' AND '2016-01-31'  
AND t2.StockType=1
GROUP BY t1.date
UNION
SELECT SUM(t2.net), 'TOTAL' 
FROM database1.invoices t1 
JOIN invoicesdetail t2 ON t1.id = t2.InvID 
WHERE shopid='11' 
AND t1.date between '2016-01-30' AND '2016-01-31'  
AND t2.StockType=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sum them up:

```
SELECT sum(t2.net), t1.date
FROM database1.invoices t1
JOIN invoicesdetail t2 ON t1.id = t2.InvID
WHERE shopid='11' AND t1.date BETWEEN '2016-01-30' AND '2016-01-31' AND t2.StockType=1
GROUP BY t1.date
```